# How to convert integer to unsigned 64-bit integer

Tags: c#, ruby

I'm converting this code from C# to Ruby:

**C# Code**

```
DateTime dtEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc); 
string strTimeStamp = Convert.ToUInt64((DateTime.UtcNow - dtEpoch).TotalSeconds).ToString();
```

**Ruby Code**

```
now = Time.now.utc
epoch = Time.utc(1970,01,01, 0,0,0)
time_diff = ((now - epoch).to_s).unpack('Q').first.to_s
```

I need to convert the integer into an unsigned 64-bit integer. Is unpack really the way to go?

Comment: `unpack` is not your thing. `Time.now.to_i` will be enough.

Comment: @Aetherus    time_diff = ((now - epoch).to_i).to_s     like this?

Comment: You don't need `epoch`, since ruby always stores times as the seconds since epoch.

Comment: @Aetherus what about converting to 64-bit?

Comment: You don't have to, since ruby automatically coerces the integer type so that it doesn't fight against your common sence.

Comment: A bit verbose explanation: ruby stores integers as instances of `Fixnum`, if that number fits the 63-bit size (not 64-bit, weird huh?) If that number exceeds that size, ruby automatically converts it to a `Bignum`, which has an arbitrary size.

Comment: @Aetherus could you post this comment as an answer? thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, `Time.now.to_i` is enough.

Ruby internally stores `Time`s in seconds since `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000`:

```
Time.now.to_f  #=> 1439806700.8638804
Time.now.to_i  #=> 1439806700
```

And you don't have to convert the value to something like `ulong` in C#, because Ruby automatically coerces the integer type so that it doesn't fight against your common sence.

A bit verbose explanation: ruby stores integers as instances of `Fixnum`, if that number fits the 63-bit size (not 64-bit, weird huh?) If that number exceeds that size, ruby automatically converts it to a `Bignum`, which has an arbitrary size.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what is the returned value for your code, but it sure ain't seconds since epoch.

Ruby stores dates and times internally as seconds until epoch. `Time.now.to_i` will return exactly what you're looking for.

```
require 'date'

# Seconds from epoch to this very second
puts Time.now.to_i

# Seconds from epoch until today, 00:00
puts Date.today.to_time.to_i
```